# Convert listbox items to a list in VBA

Tags: vba, list, listbox

I am creating a form in Visual studio where the user drags and drops files into a listbox. The filepaths are displayed in the listbox correctly but but I'm having problems doing anything with those paths. I assume the best way is to convert the paths to a list of strings?

My list is called "attachment_list" and the listbox is called "attachment entry".

whatever method I try, visual studio give me an error relating to listbox items cannot be converted to a string.

Comment: Access or excel? Strangely enough i think the difference is relevant

Comment: also here is a neat link which may answer your quesiton in a not so direct fashion     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278420/getting-listbox-items-to-array-using-access-vba

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following:

```
    Dim attachment_list As New List(Of String)
    For Each item As String In attachment_entry.Items
        attachment_list.Add(item)
    Next
```

Comment: This is VB.net not VBA. Please use the correct tags.